# PL/SQL function unknown compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-function

Total beginner to PL/SQL

Suppose i have 2 tables,

One is `REGION(R_KEY, R_NAME)`

and another one called `NATION(N_KEY, N_NAME, N_REGIONKEY)` where `N_REGIONKEY` matches a value in `R_KEY`

example 
in `REGION` we have

```
╔═══════╦════════════════╗
║ R_KEY ║     R_Name     ║
╠═══════╬════════════════╣
║     0 ║ AFRICA         ║
║     1 ║ SOUTHEAST ASIA ║
║     2 ║ EUROPE         ║
╚═══════╩════════════════╝
```

and in `NATION`

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ N_KEY ║  N_NAME   ║ N_REGIONKEY ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
║     0 ║ INDONESIA ║           1 ║
║     1 ║ LONDON    ║           2 ║
║     2 ║ FRANCE    ║           2 ║
║     3 ║ KENYA     ║           0 ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to create a function that can take in a regionName as it's parameter, and it will then list out all the nations in that region.

I have tried

```
create or replace function LISTNATION(regionName IN region.r_name%type)
return varchar2
IS
result varchar2(500)
begin
    for aRow IN (select r_key, r_name, n_name
                 from nation n, region r
                 where n_regionkey = r_Key
                 and r_key = regionKey)
    loop
        result := result || aRow.name || ', ';
    end loop;
    return result;
end LISTNATION;
```

but this returned a compilation error

Why does this compilation error happen, and is there anyway that we get notified which part of our code is causing these errors?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semi-colon, here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LISTNATION (regionName IN region.r_name%TYPE)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   result  VARCHAR2 (500);                         --> here
BEGIN
   FOR aRow IN (SELECT r_key, r_name, n_name
                  FROM nation n, region r
                 WHERE     n_regionkey = r_Key
                       AND r_key = regionKey)
   LOOP
      result := result || aRow.name || ', ';
   END LOOP;

   RETURN result;
END LISTNATION;
/
```

If you get an error, query USER_ERRORS, e.g.

```
SQL> create or replace function LISTNATION(regionName IN region.r_name%type)
  2  return varchar2
  3  IS
  4  result varchar2(500)
  5  begin
  6      for aRow IN (select r_key, r_name, n_name
  7                   from nation n, region r
  8                   where n_regionkey = r_Key
  9                   and r_key = regionKey)
 10      loop
 11          result := result || aRow.name || ', ';
 12      end loop;
 13      return result;
 14  end LISTNATION;
 15  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> select * from user_errors where name = 'LISTNATION';

NAME                           TYPE           SEQUENCE       LINE   POSITION
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ATTRIBUTE MESSAGE_NUMBER
--------- --------------
LISTNATION                     FUNCTION              1          5          1
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

   := ; not null default character
The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.
ERROR                103


SQL>
```

Or, if you're using SQL*Plus, `show errors` does the same (only prettier):

```
SQL> show err
Errors for FUNCTION LISTNATION:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         := ; not null default character
         The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

SQL>
```